# Use AWS API and RDS to securely access data

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, security

I want an API which can query a MySQL database and return the desired data. Currently for development, I am using a AWS lambda. I am passing an access token in the request, so I am able to verify that a valid user is making the request. However, when I fetch data from the database, I am logging on to the database using a username and password and the database is open for public access. I think this application has security vulnerabilities because if anyone knows the database endpoint, they can brute force the username and password.

Is there a more secure approach in accomplishing this. The general workflow is:

API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS (MySQL) -> Client

And the vulnerability I would like to avoid is the open access of the RDS MySQL DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the Lambda function to run inside the VPC with the RDS instance, and then disable public access to the RDS instance.

Comment: Does this affect the throughput of the lambda function to have it running inside a VPC?

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect throughput.